# nodejs crypto.createPrivateKey() fails on electronjs if the private key is encrypted

Tags: node.js, cryptography, electron

Using nodejs **crypto** module (i.e. `const nodecrypto = require('crypto')`); , I'm trying to sign a data using a private key. This is a combination of `crypto.createPrivateKey()` and `crypto.sign()` respectively.

While this works fine when the code is executed in pure node; it fails when the very same code is executed in electronjs, with this error:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: error:13000077:PKCS8 routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNKNOWN_ALGORITHM
    at Object.createPrivateKey (node:internal/crypto/keys:618:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\ElectronWithCrypto\index.js:5:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1175:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:12)
    at c._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13339)...
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

**Here's what I've tried so far**

1. upgraded to the latest version of nodejs and electron
2. upgraded to latest version of nodejs LTS and electron
3. downgraded nodejs to LTS version that the latest electron specifically supports (as per electron v21.0.0, it is nodejs v16.16.0)

**Thanks!**

---

**If anyone's interested, here's the very basic code to repro the issue:**

1. run it with `node index.js` - no error
2. run it with `npm start` - produces the error

**index.js** (don't worry about the private key, this one is self-signed, and created only to showcase the scenario/problem). I have not included the signing part.

---

```
const nodecrypto = require('crypto');
var privateKey = '-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----\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\n-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----';

var privKey = nodecrypto.createPrivateKey({
    key: privateKey,
    passphrase: 'test',
    encoding: 'utf-8'
});
```

**package.json**

---

```
{
  "name": "ElectronWithCrypto",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^21.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have yet to find a solution, but I am suffering from the same or very similar issue. I'm getting a 'Digest method not supported' error thrown by the native Node.js crypto library. The same code and dependencies run fine in a pure node.js environment, but throw an error when run within the context of Electron.